# Dynamic content in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have little problem with Bootstrap modal. I embedded HTML code in PHP. For some reasons I want couple of modals in page.

```
<?php
   //Looping modals...
    for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
        echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">';
          echo 'Launch demo modal';
        echo '</button>';
        echo '<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">';
          echo '<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">';
            echo '<div class="modal-content">';
              echo '<div class="modal-header">';
                echo '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';
                echo '<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">';
                    echo $i; //Title goes here.
                echo '</h4>';
              echo '</div>';
              echo '<div class="modal-body">';
                echo '...'; //Content goes here.
             echo ' </div>';
              echo '<div class="modal-footer">';
                echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>';
                echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>';
              echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
          echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```

Loop works fine but I can't update title and content I my modal. All content and title data stays the same. 
I tried this:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });
});
```

Well...I'm not sure how to use this correctly. 
I mean I don't know hot to use jQuery in PHP code. I tried saving jQuery code in script.js file and including in my modal:

```
echo '<script type = "text/javascript">';
    include ('script.js');
echo '</script>';
```

Anyway, that doesn't work.
So, how to change modal content dynamically?

Comment: *"All content and title data stays the same."*  Can you give an example of this bad output?  And better yet, show us what it *should* look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the modal ID every time you loop - so add the $i var in the modal ID for example. You must have unique IDs in HTML or jQuery / Bootstrap modal won't find the correct modal.

Change

```
echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal'.$i.'">';
```

and

```
echo '<div class="modal fade" id="myModal'.$i.'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">';
```

Alternately, you might rather try [varying modal content based on a trigger button](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target).

Also - just a style note: You can have multi-line echo statements, which might make your code a little easier to read. Or close the PHP tage and re-open when done with HTML:

```
echo '
<div ... >
    <div ... >
    </div>
</div>
';
```

or (instead of echo):

```
<?php
for ($i ... ) {
    ?>
    <div ... >
        <div ... >
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
} //ending for loop 
?>
```